# How to change the youtube playlist ID with a drop down

Tags: jquery, youtube-api

I am writing a page that pulls all the IDs from my Youtube channel, then displays them on the left side.

When you click on them, they should load into the larger video player.

However, what I also want is to use the drop-down to load the specific ID and refresh to the playlist.

This is where I am at and I am now stuck:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var key = 'AIzaSyDu_WUtnA_2tJCKUYRjgJbkejgJyQTr-zc';
    var playlistId = ['PL1AE4427D4BE1FC08', 'PLE9cFSHEPaoHuOprDwha-8g18M5nbxUDY',
        ' PL3834F0575C7DDAF5', 'PLC8575C947E2F534E', 
        'PLE9cFSHEPaoE7qLUn398ncEBUYXKVLcZ0', 
        'PLE9cFSHEPaoEq9gtNryPHV2M3DmSEHKoS', 
        'PLA75344A6D4A313CC',
        'PLE9cFSHEPaoGrH1aaYQEI-iTv5Lgrrvtv', 
        'PLE9cFSHEPaoH1uBvx62reZNGzjAtTSVYT', 'PL47BE509053B369FE'];
    var URL = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems';
    var URL2 = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos'

$( "#sel_status" ).val();
    var sel = document.getElementById('sel_status').selectedIndex;
    var i = sel;
    var options = {
        part: 'snippet',
        key: key,
        maxResults: 50,
        playlistId: playlistId[i]
    }

https://jsbin.com/taruheg/edit?html,css,js,output
```

Comment: Could you explain which part of your code is causing problems for you here?

Comment: Basically where i am stuck is i can't get the drop down to change the playlistId: playlistId[i] so that it will load the different playlists

Comment: This part is confusing: "However, what I also want is to use the drop-down to load the specific ID and refresh to the playlist." (please don't explain it to me here, but instead edit the question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make changes in your `HTML` and `jQuery` code to make this work:

**HTML**

```
<main class="col-4">
    <div class="ddown sticky-top">
        <label for="DropDown">Choose a video playlist&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
        <select id="sel_status" name="sel_status">
            <option value="0">Products and Equipment</option>
            <option value="1">Car Wash Quick Hits</option>
            <option value="2">How To</option>
            <option value="3">Soap and Chemicals</option>
            <option value="4">Car Wash Smart Talk</option>
            <option value="5">Commercials</option>
            <option value="6">Detail</option>
            <option value="7">Chelsea Knows</option>
            <option value="8">Car Wash Spotlight</option>
            <option value="9">Dog Wash</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="plylist_wrapper"></div>
</main>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var key = 'AIzaSyDu_WUtnA_2tJCKUYRjgJbkejgJyQTr-zc';
    var playlistId = ['PL1AE4427D4BE1FC08', 'PLE9cFSHEPaoHuOprDwha-8g18M5nbxUDY',' PL3834F0575C7DDAF5', 'PLC8575C947E2F534E', 'PLE9cFSHEPaoE7qLUn398ncEBUYXKVLcZ0', 'PLE9cFSHEPaoEq9gtNryPHV2M3DmSEHKoS', 'PLA75344A6D4A313CC', 'PLE9cFSHEPaoGrH1aaYQEI-iTv5Lgrrvtv', 'PLE9cFSHEPaoH1uBvx62reZNGzjAtTSVYT', 'PL47BE509053B369FE'];
    var URL = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems';
    var URL2 = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos';

    var sel = document.getElementById('sel_status').selectedIndex;
    var options = {
        part: 'snippet',
        key: key,
        maxResults: 50,
        playlistId: playlistId[sel]
    }

    loadVids( options );

    // CLICK EVENT
    $('main').on('click', 'article', function () {
        var id = $(this).attr('data-key');
        mainVid(id);
    });

    $('#sel_status').change(function() {
        var playlistIndex = $(this).prop('selectedIndex');
        options.playlistId = playlistId[playlistIndex];
        $('.plylist_wrapper').html('');
        loadVids( options );
    });

    function loadVids( options ) {
        $.getJSON(URL, options, function (data) {
            var id = data.items[0].snippet.resourceId.videoId;
            mainVid(id);
            resultsLoop(data);
        });
    }

    //THIS FUNCTION WILL USE THE VIDEO ID FROM PREVIOUS API CALL AND RETRIEVE VIEW COUNT
    function view_count(vid) {
       var opt = {
           part: 'statistics',
           key: key,
           id: vid,
       }
       var vc = null;

       $.getJSON(URL2, opt, function (data) {
           vc = data.items[0].statistics.viewCount;
           $('#'+vid).append(`<p>Views: ${vc}</p>`);
       });
    }

    function mainVid(id) {
        $('#video').html(`
            <iframe width="100%" height="700" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/${id}" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        `);
    }

    function resultsLoop(data) {
        $.each(data.items, function (i, item) {

            var thumb = item.snippet.thumbnails.medium.url;
            var title = item.snippet.title;
            var desc = item.snippet.description.substring(0, 80);
            var vid = item.snippet.resourceId.videoId;
            var view = view_count(vid); //CALL FOR VIEWS

            $('.plylist_wrapper').append(`
                <article class="item" data-key="${vid}">
                    <img src="${thumb}" alt="" class="thumb">
                        <div class="details" id="${vid}">
                            <h5>${title}</h5>
                            <p>${desc}</p>
                        </div>
                 </article>
            `);
        });
    }
});
```